# Binomial expansion inequality for (1+x) versus n(n-1)/2

Tags: calculus

Any help would be appreciated!

Show that:

$$(1+x)^n>\frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2$$

for all x>0

By taking $$x=\sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}}$$ show that $$(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^2<\frac{2}{n-1}$$

Hence find $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[n]{n}$$

Thanks in advance!

What I tried until I got stuck:

LHS > $$(n-1)(n-2)(x^{n-2}+x^2) \div 2$$

RHS = $$n(n-1)x^2 \div 2$$

Comment: Velcome to the site!

Comment: Vell said. ${}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that
$$
(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k
$$
Now you simply cancel every term of the sum except the one for $k=2$.

You want to show that $s_n:=\sqrt[n]n-1$ converges to zero (that will answer your question).
Observe that $(1+s_n)^n=n$ and apply the estimate. I can help you with the remaining parts if needed.

Comment: That will yield $\binom{n}{2} x^2$, which leads to $\frac{n(n-1)}{2 }x^2$. Thanks a lot! Much easier than I thought!

Comment: I don't want to be a legal eagle here, but the question nowhere states that $n$ is an integer. Binomial expansion of only valid for integral exponents. What one has to do here is use the Taylor series of $(1+x)^n$. Otherwise, the proof proceeds the same way.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This is indeed true. That's the power of conventions...